# Login in liferay application using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, liferay-6

I am not able to login in a liferay application while replaying Jmeter script.

I have added **HTTP Cookie Manager** and update jmeter.properties file

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

I did not find any authentication token or dynamic id to handle.

While I logged in any non liferay application it is OK and I am getting login

Everything is seems correct by my side.

[image]

Comment: try option 3 from here: https://www.communardo.de/techblog/liferay-performance-testing/ (essentially 2-stage login process, and extract authtoken in addition to cookies)

Comment: Token is not generated.. Please refer screen shot

Comment: authtoken is in HTTP response body, not in cookies (so you need to use regex extractor to retrieve it). Do you have a screenshot for form/login response?

Comment: I did the same .extracted an authToken from previous  request's response and because of there is no authToken parameter in login post request I added a parameter named authToken and pass the value extracted from the previous sampler but I am still stuck . do not have any clue.